# ViewPager2: set a different padding for first and last page

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I have implemented a "page peek" feature for my ViewPager2:

```
private fun setViewPager() {
    inventoryVp?.apply {
        clipToPadding = false   // allow full width shown with padding
        clipChildren = false    // allow left/right item is not clipped
        offscreenPageLimit = 2  // make sure left/right item is rendered
    }

    inventoryVp?.setPadding(Utility.dpToPx(25), 0, Utility.dpToPx(25), 0)

    val pageMarginPx = Utility.dpToPx(6)
    val marginTransformer = MarginPageTransformer(pageMarginPx)
    inventoryVp?.setPageTransformer(marginTransformer)
}
```

Doing this I am able to view a portion of the previous and next page. But first and last page show a bigger white space because there's no other page in this direction to show.

How can I set a different padding for the first and last page?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using ItemDecoration.

```
class CartOOSVPItemDecoration(val marginStart: Int,
                           val marginEnd: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
        outRect.left = marginStart
    }
    else if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == ((parent.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0) - 1)) {
        outRect.right = marginEnd
    }

}
}

 inventoryVp?.addItemDecoration( CartOOSVPItemDecoration(Utility.dpToPx(-9), Utility.dpToPx(-9)))
```